# Arrays of structures passed to another method

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I create array of structures in one of my functions and I want to use that array of structures in another file. my structure is this:

```
struct competitors{
int competitorNumber;
char registeredCourse;
char name[50];
};
```

**EDIT: Sorry I copied wrong structure!!!**

This is how I populate my structure:

```
lines = lineCount(fileName);
struct checkPoints checkPoint[lines];
sizeOfCheckPoints = lines;
chPo = fopen(fileName, mode);
if (chPo == NULL) {
    printf("Can't find the files.");
    exit(1);
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
        fscanf(chPo, "%c %d %d %d:%d\n", &checkPoint[i].dropOut, &checkPoint[i].currentPoint, &checkPoint[i].competitor, &checkPoint[i].hour, &checkPoint[i].minute);
    }
}
```

It populates structure perfectly fine, but I have no idea how should I use it in another file. This is how I tried using it, but it seems not to work:

```
for(i = 0; i<sizeOfCompetitors; i++){
    if (name == competitor[i].name){
        printf("Here is comp details: %d\t%c\t%s", competitor[i].competitorNumber, competitor[i].registeredCourse, competitor[i].name);
    }else{
        printf("%s was not found", name);
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me with that?

Comment: Where is `.competitorNumber`? or competitor array? or `.name`?

Comment: the structure itself is an array so `competitor[i]` (as it shows second bit of my code. `competitorNumber` and `name` is saved in `struct competitor` (first bit of code). Basically my question is: how to access array of structures in different file.

Comment: What is `competitor` and `name`?

Comment: Sorry guys, such a silly mistake i copied wrong structure, i put in correct one now

Answer (score 1):

You want your struct definition in a .h file so both .c files know about it.

Then you can just use it! The best way would be passing it in from the first file to the second. You probably want to declare your methods in the .h file too
e.g.
    /* checkpoint.h */
    /* your struct def */
    /* perhaps a typedef for it */
    /* declaration of methods */
    void doSomething(struct checkPoints *points, int numPounts);

```
/* second dot C */
#include "checkpoint.h"
void doSomething(struct checkPoints *points, int numPounts)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        int currentPoint = points[i].currentpoint;
        ...
```